# Looping through array and assigning certain values to another array

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop

So I have an array that has 16 elements. I know that within this array there is 2 elements that I dont want. So i declared another array with size 14. However, how do I loop through the 16 elements array and assign those 14 variables to the new array without there being blank spaces, as those other 2 values are used at a point in the loop too.

For example:

```
double firstArray[16] = {10.0, 2.0, 3.4, 7.0, 50.0, 1.2, 4.2, 6.8, 8.9, 7.9, 8.6, 2.1, 3.2, 4.7, 8.9, 0.8};
```

I want to loop through this array and put all the values except 2.0 and 3.4 into:

```
 double secondArray[14]
```

I have been using a foor loop but since it uses the same index, it leaves blank spaces in the second array and doesnt get to the end.

Comment: You know how to loop over an array? You know how to assign values from one variable to another? You know how to access an element of an array at a specific index? You know how to increase variables by one? Then you really know all you need to know. So please try to create a [mcve] to show us, and tell us what the problem is with that. Perhaps also take some time to refresh on [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: You clearly know that not all of the elements of the source array will end up at the same location in the destination array, so you cannot use the source array index as the destination array index -- at least, not directly.  What else could you do?

Answer (score 1):

Declare two variables as indices in the for-loop.

Here you are

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 16 };
    double firstArray[N] = 
    {
        10.0, 2.0, 3.4, 7.0, 50.0, 1.2, 4.2, 6.8, 
        8.9, 7.9, 8.6, 2.1, 3.2, 4.7, 8.9, 0.8
    };

    double secondArray[N - 2];

    for ( size_t i = 0, j = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        if ( firstArray[i] != 2.0 && firstArray[i] != 3.4 )
        {
            secondArray[j++] = firstArray[i];
        }           
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N - 2; i++ ) printf( "%.1f ", secondArray[i] );
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
10.0 7.0 50.0 1.2 4.2 6.8 8.9 7.9 8.6 2.1 3.2 4.7 8.9 0.8
```

In fact you need not to define a second array. You could move the undesired values at the end of the original array and keep the new value of the actual elements in the array.